# Kendoui dataviz adding data points on line charts

Tags: charts, kendo-ui, real-time, kendo-dataviz

Is it possible to add a new and remove data points on a kendoUI line chart without refreshing the chart? 
Data will be coming in every 5 seconds and can go upto a maximum of 720 data points on the chart (chart will be showing data for the past one hour). If 720 data points are available on the chart the next data coming in should be appended at the end of the chart while removing the first data point on the chart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion is to manipulate the data points via [the API](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods) of the chart Data Source.

One refresh every 5 seconds or so shouldn't be a problem, especially if you turn off [transitions](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/chart#refresh):

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    transitions: false
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Got a demo link from a KendoUI representative which does dynamic data updates on a chart. I guess this should help.

http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/api/benchmark.html